# NHibernate 3.1.0 Linq

Tags: linq, nhibernate

There are a number of posts on here mentioning Linq support in NHibernate, but they are 2 years old. NHibernate 3.1.0 has a built-in Linq provider. I am wondering what kind of limitations it has, or should I charge forward in knowing that I won't run into too many problems? Will I end up having to use the native query language in NHibernate due to limitations in the Linq provider?

Comment: This looks interesting.  But like you said, it is old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624609/linq-to-nhibernate

Comment: Luckily nothing in technology ever changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.x LINQ provider keeps getting better. It supports lots of constructs, although not as many as EF. It's really usable.

Now, you write *"Will I end up having to use the native query language in NHibernate"* like it was a bad thing. It's not.

NHibernate has 5 different query methods (Criteria, HQL, LINQ, QueryOver and SQL). Each has its strengths and weaknesses, adapting better to different usage scenarios.

My suggestion is that you learn them all, and use whatever fits best what you're trying to do in each case. LINQ, regardless of the provider, is always leaky when talking to a SQL DB. Keep that in mind.

Comment: I think you would be hard pressed to find a query that isn't supported by Query or QueryOver.

Comment: @Phill: supported is one thing, practical is another. I've seen people write 30 lines of convoluted QueryOver when a simple 5-line HQL would have worked much better.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should do everything in QueryOver, I think the most I've written is maybe 8 or 9 lines. But I do think it does cater for 95%? of the queries people write...